# How can I make the indicators on my drop-down sections toggle without activating the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a page that has several drop-downs, with a plus/minus indicator next to the title. The problem is that when I click on the titles, *all* of the indicators fire off.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div class="linkBox">
    <div class="slide" id="s1"><h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> Title</h4></div>
    <div class="content" id="c1">
        <p>
        Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque naturae; Efficiens dici potest. Addidisti ad extremum etiam indoctum fuisse. Optime, inquam.Polycratem Samium felicem appellabant. Summus dolor plures dies manere non potest? Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens. Non laboro, inquit, de nomine. Quid censes in Latino fore?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tubulo putas dicere?
    </p>
    <br>
    <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="s2"><h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> Title</h4></div>
    <div class="content" id="c2">
        <p>
        Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque naturae; Efficiens dici potest. Addidisti ad extremum etiam indoctum fuisse. Optime, inquam.Polycratem Samium felicem appellabant. Summus dolor plures dies manere non potest? Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens. Non laboro, inquit, de nomine. Quid censes in Latino fore?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tubulo putas dicere?
    </p>
    <br>
    <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="s3"><h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> Title</h4></div>
    <div class="content" id="c3">
        <p>
            Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque naturae; Efficiens dici potest. Addidisti ad extremum etiam indoctum fuisse. Optime, inquam.Polycratem Samium felicem appellabant. Summus dolor plures dies manere non potest? Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens. Non laboro, inquit, de nomine. Quid censes in Latino fore?
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tubulo putas dicere?
        </p>
        <br>
        <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Here's the script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('h4').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().next().slideToggle()
            .siblings('.content').slideUp();
            $('.ind').toggle(this).nextAll().preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

I've been stuck on this for quite a while, so the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$('.ind').toggle(this).nextAll().preventDefault();` ? what's this supposed to do? `preventDefault` is a method of the `Event` constructor, not of a jQuery Object collection of elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: It's a leftover from when I was experimenting, my apologies for the confusion. I'm very new to JQuery and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `plus+` should be showed if the content is `slideup`, and `minus-` should be showed if the content is `slidedown`, so by default show `+` and content is hidden.

--by add the following to html:

```
    <style>
      .ind.plus{
        display:inline;
      }

      .ind.minus{
        display: none;
      }

      .content{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
```

So you can update js to control your `indicators`.

js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('h4').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().next().slideToggle()
                .siblings('.content').slideUp();

                $(this).find(".ind").toggle();

                $(this).parent().siblings('.slide').find('.ind.plus').show();
                $(this).parent().siblings('.slide').find('.ind.minus').hide();


            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually far easier than you're making it on yourself.

In your above code, you're running `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle().siblings('.content').slideUp()`. In addition to toggling the next element in the DOM (the related `.content`), you're also sliding up all of the **other** `.content` elements.

As you simply want to toggle the related content, all you need to do is find the very next element, and `slideToggle()` that; it's always going to be a `.content` element.

Your second line `$('.ind').toggle(this).nextAll().preventDefault();` appears to be attempting to 'correct' the behaviour from your first line, and can be omitted entirely.

Here's the updated code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h4').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="linkBox">
  <div class="slide" id="s1">
    <h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> POSitouch</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="c1">
    <p>
      POSitouch is a cutting edge POS software designed for the Hospitality industry, and is the preferred solution among top operators because of the many features it provides. It is faster, easier and smarter than any other system available on the market
      today and because of its adaptability with regards to most hardware platforms and mobile device. With POSitouch, there are no feature needs which can't be met, or POS operational challenges left unaddressed, which is why it receives the highest
      recognition and client satisfaction ratings year over year.
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Whether you are an independent restaurant or a national chain, bar or hotel, CCP will provide the Point of Sale (POS) system that can best adapt to your way of doing business and help your operation be more profitable and efficient.
    </p>
    <br>
    <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="slide" id="s2">
    <h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> DinerWare</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="c2">
    <p>
      Used by thousands of restaurant owners, Diner Ware provides superior reliability and advanced technology for the budget conscious operator.
      <p>
        <br>
        <p>
          Diner Ware Point-of-Sale software is an essential tool which affords a lower cost of ownership. It streamlines your operation, and enables you to focus more on your customers. Its advanced capability and intuitive user interface makes it extremely simple
          to use.
        </p>
        <br>
        <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="slide" id="s3">
    <h4><span class="plus ind">+</span><span class="minus ind">-</span> CCP Cloud</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="c3">
    <p>
      Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque naturae; Efficiens dici potest. Addidisti ad extremum etiam indoctum fuisse. Optime, inquam.Polycratem Samium felicem appellabant. Summus dolor plures dies manere non potest? Beatus sibi videtur esse moriens. Non
      laboro, inquit, de nomine. Quid censes in Latino fore?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tubulo putas dicere?
    </p>
    <br>
    <h3>Click here for more information.</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note that if you want to hide up the **other** `.content` elements, it's much more sound to simply `.hide()` them by default :)

Hope this helps! :)